# bootstrap modal can't call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I was trying to load dynamic data on my bootstrap modal. But button can't call the javascript function so instead of loading dynamic data it only loads the on page modal. What could be possible error of the following code?

```
<a href="#"  style="color:#4fc6e1; margin-left:10px;" data-id="{{ $row->id }}" data-target="#cart-modal" data-toggle="modal"  > <i data-feather="plus-square"></i> </a>
```

Bootstrap Modal:

```
<div id="cart-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Warehouse Products</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          </div>
               
          <div class="modal-body cart p-4">
                         
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
                
          </div>
              
      </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Javascript Part:

```
 $("#cart-modal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
     
        var product_id = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
        var url = '{{ url('product-details') }}';

        $.ajax({
           url:url,
           method:'POST',
           data:{ product_id: product_id },

           success:function(response){

              if(response.success){
                    $(".modal-body cart").html(response.html);
              }else{
                  console.log(error)
              }
           },
           error:function(error){
              console.log(error)
           }

        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi, here `$(".modal-body cart")` should be `$(".modal-body.cart")`

Comment: that doesn't change my action. actually can't call the javascript function.

Comment: see any error inside browser console ?

Comment: nope. nothing in console

Comment: See if that [alert()](https://jsfiddle.net/1gc72b0a/) shows in your code as well . Also , check network tab if the ajax call intiated or not .